# Php only numbers Validating function

Tags: php, validation

I would like to create a validate function for numbers only, actually I have those ones that works fine, and I tried to create one myself, but it's unfortunately not working. Here are the alphanumeric and others working fine :

```
// Validators
private function custom($validator, $value)
{
    return call_user_func($validator, $value, $this->request, $this->id);
}

private function alphanumeric($value, $custom)
{
    return preg_match('/^(['.$custom.'a-z0-9_]*)$/i', $value);
}

private function valid_email($value)
{
    return preg_match('/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/', $value);
}
```

And the one I tried to create by modifying the alphanumeric one :

```
private function numbers_only($value, $custom)
{
    return preg_match('/^(['.$custom.'0-9_]*)$/i', $value);
}
```

What's wrong with this one ?

EDIT :
I also have a JS helping with the form, for alphanumeric it's :

```
Form.prototype.alphanumeric = function(value, custom)
{
    return !value.replace(new RegExp('['+custom+'a-z0-9_]', 'ig'), '').length;
};
```

What would be the JS for numeric only ?

Comment: use the D flag unless you want to allow a trailing new line.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use

```
is_numeric($value);
```

return is true or false

Comment: Use caution with [is_numeric()](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php).  Things like scientific notation `1e4` will return true.

Answer (score 7):

If you want only numbers, remove the `$custom` part from the function.  The `/i` implies case-insensitive matching, which is not relevant for numeric matches, and so can be removed.

```
private function numbers_only($value)
{
    return preg_match('/^([0-9]*)$/', $value);
}
```

The expression above will match zero or more numbers, so blank input is allowed. To require at least one number, change `*` to `+` as in

```
return preg_match('/^([0-9]+)$/', $value);
```

And the `[0-9]+` can be abbreviated as `\d+`.  Since you are not capturing the value inside a an array of matches, there is no need for the extra overhead which is added by including the `()` capture group. That can be omitted as well.

```
return preg_match('/^\d+$/', $value);
```

#### Or skip the regex entirely...

Finally, if you've gotten this far and are matching only integers, it is far easier and less resource-intensive to just do:

```
// If you really intend to match numbers only, and not all numeric values
// which might include .,
function numbers_only($value)
{
  return ctype_digit(strval($value));
}
```

Comment: What would be the JS corresponding to `ctype_digit` ?

Comment: @Jamescoo Don't think there is one. In JavaScript, regex is usually used.

Answer (score 4):

In PHP, for a "only numbers" validation you can use different approaches:

- is_int or is_integer
- is_numeric
- regular expressions
- ctype_digit
- filter_var

**is_integer()**

for this function these values are are not valid: "0010", "123"

**is_numeric()**

for this function these values are valid: 1.3, +1234e44 and 0x539

**filter_var()**

for this function a value as "00123" is not valid

**CONSLUSION**

it seems that only **regex** and **ctype_digit** work always fine.

**TEST**

[a simple test here](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/z1zx-csdg)